# Azure Service Fabric 32 bit support

Tags: azure, 32bit-64bit, azure-service-fabric

Please let me know whether service fabric supports capability similar to WoW64 ?

I have a 32 bit .NET application which depends on 32 bit unmanged c++ dlls.  Is it possible to run this application in Service Fabric in any way?

Answer (score 5):

You can host any existing applications in Service Fabric (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-deploy-existing-app/). However if you want to use reliable collections, reliable actors APIs, your application needs to be 64 bit. For management operations on cluster Service Fabric provides REST APIs, so you can use any HTTP stack from a 32 bit application to manage the applications in the cluster.